# KVM NIC passthrough "device already in use"

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nic, pci

I have a server with 2 NICs

> 01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller
>   10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)
>   01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller
>   10-Gigabit X540-AT2 (rev 01)

and i want to assign theise 2 NICs devices to a guest (ubuntu server 14.04) , i'm folowing this topic [this topic  :How to assign devices with VT-d in KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM) 
so i did what it's says :

- Modifying kernel config :

  > make menuconfig
  >   set "Bus options (PCI etc.)" -> "Support for DMA Remapping Devices" to "*"
  >   set "Bus options (PCI etc.)" -> "Enable DMA Remapping Devices" to "*"
  >   set "Bus options (PCI etc.)" -> "PCI Stub driver" to "*"
  >   save and rebuild kernel
- my **dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU** shows :

  > [    0.000000] ACPI: DMAR 00000000ddfaabc8 000078 (v01 INTEL      SNB
  >   00000001 INTL 00000001)
  >   [    0.000000] Intel-IOMMU: enabled
  >   [    0.018789] dmar: IOMMU 0: reg_base_addr fed90000 ver 1:0 cap >c9008020660262 ecap f010da
  >   [    0.018860] IOAPIC id 2 under DRHD base  0xfed90000 IOMMU 0
  >   [    1.610427] DMAR: No ATSR found
  >   [    1.610449] IOMMU 0 0xfed90000: using Queued invalidation
  >   [    1.610451] IOMMU: Setting RMRR:
  >   [    1.610460] IOMMU: Setting identity map for device 0000:00:1d.0 >[0xdde16000 - 0xdde32fff]
  >   [    1.610478] IOMMU: Setting identity map for device 0000:00:1a.0 >[0xdde16000 - 0xdde32fff]
  >   [    1.610487] IOMMU: Prepare 0-16MiB unity mapping for LPC
  >   [    1.610494] IOMMU: Setting identity map for device 0000:00:1f.0 [0x0 - 
  >   0xffffff]

  - i also Activate Intel VT-d in the kernel by appending the intel_iommu=on parameter to the kernel line of the kernel line in the /boot/grub/grub.conf file
  - setting VT-d on BIOS to enabled
  - unbind nic from host kernel driver :

    > echo "8086 10b9" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/pci-stub/new_id
    >   echo 0000:01:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver/unbind
    >   echo 0000:01:00.0 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/pci-stub/bind
  - i verified the unbinding with lspci -k : the driver was pci_stub

And when i add this folowing lines in XML file of guest vm , i got an error

> device 01:00.0 already in use

The XML add

> hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'
>    source
>        address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/
>    /source
>   /hostdev